# How to create constants when we are using VIPER architecture?

Tags: ios, swift, constants, viper-architecture

I am following VIPER design pattern to build application in Swift.

VIPER follows four components:

1) View
2) Wireframe
3) Presenter
4) Interactor

In which component my constants will come and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean constants that are being used in whole application, they should probably go into separate group, that is independent from any VIPER module. Consider following examplary structure:

```
MyProject
- Common
    - Constants
    - ...
- Modules
    - MyFirstViperModule
        - View
        - ...
    - MySecondViperModule
        - View
        - ...
- Resources
    - Assets
    - ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you begin with viper, you can use [Generamba](https://github.com/rambler-digital-solutions/Generamba) with `swifty_viper` template. this tool will help you to generate your first modules.